# High CPU load for WordPress

Tags: centos, vps, wordpress

Some plugins in WordPress are causing high CPU usage. Running atop command i can see that can php-cgi and mysql services are causing the load. Is there a way i can see via CLI what plugins are causing this mess?

Answer (score 0):

No. Try to disable all plug-in and enable them one at a time.

Sometime the mytop could help you to find if the database is a problem (lack of index) and possibly also the plugin which do slow/bad queries (like many SEO plugins).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use any SEO plugins. mysqld service reaches >100% sometimes. The database is optimized and clean of garbage and about 80 MB in size. How i can see slow/bad queries?

Comment: mytop command or log the slow queries (see the mysql configuration file, look for string 'slow'). Often plugin authors forget the basic of database, e.g. to make index when necessary of just clean queries; additionally it seems they test their plugin only with few data.